# Ошибка "refs not found"

Tags: git, github

Делаю **push** проекта:

```
$ git push origin master
```

и такое выдает:

> fatal:
> https://github.com/myusername/my-first-project-test.git/info/refs
> not found: did you run git
> update-server-info on the server?

Естественно, что команда

```
git update-server-info
```

ничем не помогает.

Вопрос: что это такое и как с ним бороться?

**updated:**

> web@SERVER ~/php-first (master)
>
> $ git push origin master
>
> Username for 'https://github.com':
>
> Password for 'https://stasonix@github.com':
>
> fatal: https://github.com/stasonix/php-first.git/info/refs not found: did you ru
> n git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: https://github.com/myusername/my-first-project-test.git/info/refs 

Repository not found.

Comment: Естественно not found, я данные для примера привел.

Comment: @Tolbase, ***данные для примера*** не могут скопировать условия при которых возникла ошибка, а, значит, **хорошего** ответа Вы не получите.

-----
Вчитайтесь: 
> fatal: https://github.com/myusername/my-first-project-test.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info **on the server**?

Comment: Вчитываюсь, on the server - на сервере, т.е. это не в Git Bash что ли промпте? Я просто не представляю, где еще эту команду ввести.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(**`Git Bash`**'у всё равно, пользуетесь **гитхабом** Вы, или у Вас **`Git`**-сервер под столом стоит, вот он и выдаёт рекомендации по решению проблемы.)*

---

`https://github.com/stasonix/php-first.git` - это Ваш репозиторий, а Вы делаете **`Push`** на `https://github.com/stasonix/php-first.git/info/refs`. Бороться с этим можно очень просто:

1. [Настройка **`Git`**](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git).
2. [Добавление **`SSH`**-ключа](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).
3. [Работа в **`Git-Bash`** с **`GitHub`**](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo) *(Тут обратите внимание на 3 шаг)*.